# Pronunciación del diptongo en aun

Tags: pronunciación, diptongos

'Aun' es utilizado sin acento cuando esta palabra se puede sustituir por 'aunque', 'siquiera' o 'incluso'.
Mientras que 'aún' con acento es utilizado cuando la palabra se puede sustituir por 'todavía'.

Mi duda es, ¿en el lenguaje hablado se tiene que pronunciar con diptongo en el caso de 'aunque'? Ejemplo: 'No renunciará a su patrimonio aun cuando tenga que luchar por él en los tribunales.' O lo que es lo mismo, ¿ 'aun' se pronuncia en una sola sílaba?

Answer (score 1):

**Aun o Aún**

*La acentuación gráfica de los adverbios aun y aún depende de su significado. Aun, sin tilde, es equivalente a 'incluso', 'hasta', 'también' o 'siquiera', mientras que aún, con tilde, significa 'todavía'.*

***La diferencia ortográfica entre aun y aún marca o representa una diferencia en la pronunciación. "Aun" se pronuncia como monosílabo átono. En cambio, "aún" se pronuncia como un bisílabo tónico [a-ún].***

***Sin embargo, la pronunciación habitual tiende a reducir a una sola sílaba el hiato marcado por la tilde en la /u/. La igualdad en la pronunciación es el motivo por el cual suele presentarse la duda en su escritura.***

Diccionario de Dudas

**Aun o Aún**

*Fabián Coelho* Lingüista

[https://www.diccionariodedudas.com/aun-o-aun/#:~:text=Aun%2C%20sin%20tilde%2C%20es%20equivalente,una%20diferencia%20en%20la%20pronunciaci%C3%B3n](https://www.diccionariodedudas.com/aun-o-aun/#:%7E:text=Aun%2C%20sin%20tilde%2C%20es%20equivalente,una%20diferencia%20en%20la%20pronunciaci%C3%B3n).